# Target message to match with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have to check csv files live and match some expression to get data.
These files can have different type of message so different matching expression.
The message can be something like that

> GuiPrinter.ProcessPrint of 116806 25374 K356 S Black Face.png 229 at 1
>   table

And I want to get  `116806 25374 K356 S Black Face.png`
. So the regex associate to this kind of file would be something like `(GuiPrinter.ProcessPrint of )(.*)([.][png|jpg|jpeg|PNG|JPG|JPEG]*)` and I can return `$result[2]`

But the message and the regex can change, so I need a common function that can return the string that I want based on the regex, the function would have `message` and `regex` parameters. Maybe for another file the string that I want would be on first position so my `$result[2]` won't work.

How can I ensure to always return the string that I want to match ?

Comment: please stop using `[` in your case

Comment: if you know all the type of messages you can create one regex that will match them all

Comment: @Fallenhero I don't know that much about regex, what should I use then ?

Comment: see @Jasmin Minstry's answer. `[qwert]*` means zero or more out of the "collection" of q, w, e, r or t. So your `[png|jpg|jpeg|PNG|JPG|JPEG]*` also matches `ppppp`, `||||` or just an empty string

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\preg_match('/GuiPrinter.ProcessPrint of(.*?)\.(gif|png|bmp|jpe?g)/', $str, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match the text `GuiPrinter.ProcessPrint` and then use `\K` to reset the starting point of the reported match.

Match any character zero or more times non greedy `.*?`, then match a dot `\.` and any of the image extensions in a non capturing group `(?:gif|png|bmp|jpe?g)` followed by a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`

[`GuiPrinter\.ProcessPrint of \K.*?\.(?:gif|png|bmp|jpe?g)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/m98pmR/1)

Note that to match the dot literally you have to escape it `\.`

For example to return 1 match using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$str = 'GuiPrinter.ProcessPrint of 116806 25374 K356 S Black Face.png 229 at 1 table';
$re = '/GuiPrinter\.ProcessPrint of \K.*?\.(?:gif|png|bmp|jpe?g)\b/';

function findMatch($message, $regex) {
    preg_match($regex, $message, $matches);
    return array_shift($matches);
}

$result = findMatch($str, $re);

if ($result) {
    echo "Found: $result";
} else {
    echo "No match.";
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/LhHZ9)